# Git pull (from Gitlab) after merge will not allow

Tags: git, gitlab

Created and approved a merge request from `dev` to a `feat/***` branch using GitLab online console.

Checked the dev branch back out:

```
git checkout dev
```

And now can't pull due to local changes. Tried:

```
git stash
git pull origin feat/****
```

And

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard
git pull origin feat/****
```

And continue to get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
... <file list> ...
```

How can I pull the newly merged changes into my local copy?

Comment: `git branch` is for creating a branch, not switching to. Did you mean `git checkout`? When in doubt, run `git status`.

Comment: Yes I did. And that actually pointed out I made a mistake in my question

Comment: This is what i understand. 
So you are working on a branch called `dev` ?
You had raised a merge request to `feat/**` that got approved.

Then you checked out `dev` again for some more work ?

Please correct me and then we can work towards answers.

Comment: Sorry- I have a dev branch. I branched dev to a feature branch, completed the feature and merged(pull) requested feature back into dev. I checkout dev so I can do some more work and this is when I come across this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some new files that will be created as a result of the new changes that you are pulling, probably already exist on disk. You will have to remove them manually, before pulling.

Comment: What would be the best way to handle this in the future so as to avoid this issue?